# Calculate hash of a pdf after generating it

Tags: javascript, hash, pdf-generation, filereader, pdfmake

I'm trying to calculate the checksum of a pdf file that I have generated (in client side) with pdfmake. The code I use is this..

```
/// docDefinition.......   

const pdfDocGenerator = pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition);

pdfDocGenerator.getBlob((blob) => {
    
    var reader = new FileReader();
        
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
        
            reader.onload = function () {
                
                var file_result = this.result; 
                var file_wordArr = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(file_result);
                var sha256_hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(file_wordArr); 
                var Hash = sha256_hash.toString(); //output result
                

            };
    });
```

But when I download the pdf and check my sha256 with some of other sites, it never matches. The hash changes everytime I generate a pdf, even though the doc definition of the pdf is the same. I tried with `getBuffer` function and it's the same result.

I'm running out of solutions. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> The hash changes everytime I generate a pdf, even though the doc definition of the pdf is the same.

A pdf generator usually puts metadata (like the *creation time* or *last manipulation time*) and a unique ID into the pdfs it creates. In spite of equal *doc definitions*, therefore, the resulting pdfs usually differ slightly resulting in different hash values.

Thus, what you observe is actually to be expected and normal.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think I have figured something out thanks to mkl answer. The trick is to do generate the hash and prompt the downloading of the file almost simultaneously.

But first, if you're using pdfMake, you will need to get the blob from _proto.download function.

```
 _proto.download = function download(filename) {
    var _this2 = this;

    if (filename === void 0) {
      filename = 'file.pdf';
    }

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      _this2.getBlob().then(function (blob) {
        Object(FileSaver_min["saveAs"])(blob, filename);
        resolve();
      }, function (result) {
        reject(result);
      });
    });
  }
```

I made a modified version of it to get the blob.

```
  _proto.downloadModified= function download(filename) {
    var _this2 = this;

    if (filename === void 0) {
      filename = 'file.pdf';
    }

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      _this2.getBlob().then(function (blob) {
      
        resolve(blob);
      }, function (result) {
        reject(result);
      });
    });
  }
```

And then I set the `name` and `lastModifiedDate`.

```
        
        
        blob.lastModifiedDate =  new Date();
        blob.name = "contrat-cession-da"
        
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
        
            reader.onload = function () {
                
                
                var file_result = this.result; // this == reader, get the loaded file "result"
                var file_wordArr = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(file_result); //convert blob to WordArray , see https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/issues/detail?id=67
                var sha256_hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(file_wordArr); //calculate SHA1 hash
                var Hash = sha256_hash.toString(); //output result
                saveAs(blob);
```

Now you can generate the hash of the blob (after you read it as Array with cryptojs) and prompt the downloading with saveAs, it will give you the same hash.